# How critical is locking - Extent and modes of failure

Tags: .net, vb.net, locking, thread-safety

I've stress tested the code below and it seems to work fine - what are the dangers of not locking in the simple case where there is a single thread writing and a separate thread reading a simple variable?

Have a class that has a public property...

```
Public Class PropHolder
    Private _myVar As Double
    Public Property myVar() As Double
        Get
            Return _myVar
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _myVar = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

...and another which uses an instance of this class

```
Public Class Form1 

Public _propHolder As New PropHolder
Delegate Sub dlgPostVar()

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        While Not BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending
            _propHolder.myVar = someValue  'worker thread writing var
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.DoWork
        While Not BackgroundWorker2.CancellationPending
            Me.Invoke(New dlgPostVar(AddressOf postVal)) 'invoke UI thread to write var
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub postVal()
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(_propHolder.myVar.ToString & vbCrLf)
    End Sub

End Class
```

In the above example myVar is continuously changing and being written to a RichTextBox as fast as the UI can keep up.  Not all of the values are captured but this is not important - let's imagine that the RichTextBox only cares about sampling the current value of myVar at its leisure.

Everything I have read leads me to believe that this is not safe to do but I have yet to make it fail, even when having two threads reading and writing (single reader, single writer) this variable incessantly.  What can go wrong here, and why?

Edit :  To be more specific, this question is more hypothetical than practical.  I know that this situation requires a lock "by the book", the question is exploring the breadth of potential consquences of not locking in this instance, hopefully in the form of a complete collection of all potential modes of failure.

One example thusfar is a read from a variable being written to :

- Thread 1 -> Reads low word from memory
- Thread 2 -> CPU moves low word of new value to memory
- Thread 2 -> CPU moves high word of new value to memory
- Thread 1 -> Reads high word from memory

Thread 1 Value is now (HighWord[new])(LowWord[old]) ** corrupt

Program failure is limited to damage caused by processing of this corrupt value.
Other consequences of this failure mode?  Are there any?

Further examples?  Books/references welcome.

Edit #2 : My intention here is to explore, in the .NET framework, the extent and form of unpredictability and errors which are intrinsic to the platform and specifically not related to the consequences of how any specific program might subsequently fail in the face of such an error.

In the example above, I am doing nothing with a value aside from writing it out as text.  If I get a bad value, I write a bad value to text - nothing explodes, the program does not crash, empires do not fall, and the orbit of Mercury remains stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need a lock in this case as variable writes to `double` are not atomic. Therefore, it is possible for this to break, just extremely unlikely.

Comment: I suppose the question I'm getting at is - what form does "break" take?  In what way would it manifest? Application hang, a crash, a temporarily corrupt value, a permanently corrupt value?

Comment: You can get corrupt reads where the value is partially written to.

Comment: In this case, for example, this would be a high-word from an old value and a low-word from a new value (or vice-versa)?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, something like that could happen.

Comment: Would it be safe to say, however, that the act of reading or writing simultaneously, and causing such corruption, would not in-and-of-itself cause a global application failure or corruption of other data aside from the variable in question?  If the application handled a corrupt value gracefully is there a risk of other issues?

Comment: Reading a partially-written to variable will not "in-and-of-itself" cause a global application failure. But, it could, for example cause a calculation to go awry, lead to an overflow, and next thing you know, a multi-million dollar rocket has [exploded](http://www.around.com/ariane.html). (Yes, the linked story is not directly or indirectly about a threading issue, but Very Bad Things can happen if values show up in your application that you weren't expecting.)

Comment: Perhaps I should reassure you that I don't intend to go out and write multithreaded programs without locks...  I am fully aware that "Very Bad Things" can happen.  It's hard to say the word "multithreaded" anywhere without a chorus of programmers chiming in to spin yarn about the dire spectre of the cross-thread bogeyman.  My intention here is to explore, in the .NET framework, the extent and form of unpredictability and errors which are intrinsic to the platform and specifically not related to the consequences of how any specific program might subsequently fail.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason pointed out, you do need a lock. You likely haven't seen this crop up yet because, as others have noted, threading issues are notoriously difficult to *reproduce*. It can take a very specific set of circumstances (including user load, other processes, amount of available memory, number of concurrent threads running in your application, and so on) to trigger this unfortunate scenario.

The idea should be fairly simple and straightforward. If a variable or other resource will be touched by a separate thread of execution, lock it before doing so. This ensures that the requesting thread has sole access to the variable or resource until it's finished with it, avoiding the likelihood that you'll corrupt data, or enter some other nasty condition that brings your machine to a standstill.

There's a good reason every class on MSDN has thread safety documentation. Microsoft takes it seriously, and so should you.

Comment: Threading issues are difficult to reproduce *when they happen as random failures in existing code*.  I believe it should be possible, however, to design a program to fail consistently and at sufficient frequency to be detectable and identifiable.  How would you write a program to cause this type of failure?  How would you prove to me, with a working example, that this type of read/write corruption will occur?

Answer (score -1):

Just because you test don't cause it issue doesn't mean it won't happen. Threading issues are the hardest to debug. The reason to lock the code is to prevent out date information or cause double processing. The issues that could happen are one thread sets the value and then another thread overrides it with out allowing it to process it. In your case you could case an issue where it is currently writing to the variable as another thread is reading from it therefore causing an issue.

From MSDN:

"All members of this type are thread safe. Members that appear to modify instance state actually return a new instance initialized with the new value. As with any other type, reading and writing to a shared variable that contains an instance of this type must be protected by a lock to guarantee thread safety.

Caution

Assigning an instance of this type is not thread safe on all hardware platforms because the binary representation of that instance might be too large to assign in a single atomic operation.

"

Comment: any reason for the down vote? I want to know to help create better responses.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one reason might be because you refer to multiple writers when the OP explicitly said this is a single-writer scenario.

Comment: ahh good point. In my response i tried to be a little generic for the purpose of the author since it seemd he lacked a basis of thread-safe.

Comment: Not my downvote either, but in any case I am well aware of the principles of thread safety and have read most everything in MSDN.  The question is more a "why" question - looking for specific modes of failure and how they manifest, ways a test could provoke or detect such a failure, etc.